# zabbix trigger on ssh logins: Invalid parameter "/1/expression": incorrect expression starting from

Tags: zabbix

Im trying to set a trigger on zabbix to alert me on ssh logins on a template.
I have created an item SSH login with log[/var/log/auth.log,"Accepted .*",,,skip,\0]

This is my expression for the trigger:

```
Linux by Zabbix agent active:log[/var/log/auth.log,"Accepted .*",,,skip,\0].change()
```

I have followed the docs here https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.2/en/manual/config/triggers/expression

I get the error message :

```
Invalid parameter "/1/expression": incorrect expression starting from "{Linux by Zabbix agent active:log[/var/log/auth.log,"Accepted .*",,,skip,\0].change()}>0".
```

I have tried with braces {}, with change(>0), with brace and >0 after (`{Linux by Zabbix agent active:log[/var/log/auth.log,"Accepted .*",,,skip,\0].change()}>0`)

Any hints on how to do that?

Thanks